# How can I add route to VPC Gateway endpoint for AWS network firewall using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to deploy AWS network firewall and getting below error.

```
Error: error creating route: InvalidParameterValue: route table rtb-060e56b4e1a9ea33c and interface eni-09505345a50ed2786 belong to different networks
    status code: 400, request id: b28dae26-ddec-42c0-b0d1-4443b224e55f

  on main.tf line 252, in resource "aws_route_table" "tgw-inspection-RT":
 252: resource "aws_route_table" "tgw-inspection-RT" {
```

Below is a piece of code where i am trying to add a route so that TGW sends all traffic to AWS Network firewall VPC endpoint.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "tgw-inspection-RT" {
  provider = aws.region-master
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.inspection-vpc.id
    route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    network_interface_id = data.aws_network_interface.firewall-int.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "tgw-inspection-RT"
  }
}
```

I tried to add using "vpc_endpoint_id = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.terraform-anf.id" but still got an error.

I tried other ways as well as mentioned in below document but i am still getting an error.
https://github.com/giuseppeborgese/terraform-aws-network-firewall-poc/blob/main/vpc.tf

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: It sounds like the network firewall isn't in the same VPC as the route table you are trying to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Cant remember where I saw that but looks like something of this nature:
`data.aws_networkfirewall_firewall.network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states`

Answer (score 0):

i got it working using this

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt_inbound" {
  count    = 3
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    vpc_endpoint_id = element(flatten(aws_networkfirewall_firewall.network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states[*].attachment[*].endpoint_id), count.index)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a count of 3?

Comment: thats because in my case i have 3 route table